# how access to new vertices after bmesh.ops.bisect_edges?

Tags: scripting, add-on, vertices, edges, bmesh

I'm trying to access to new vertices after apply  bmesh.ops.bisect_edges

API say that newly created vertices and edges will be in geom_split.  I can print"geom_split" data, but I can't access to new vertices, only I can see the information in console.

here code... thanks for any help

```
import bpy
import bmesh
import mathutils
import math


obj = bpy.context.object
me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

edges= [e for e in bm.edges if (e.select==True and not e.hide)]


if len(edges) < 2:
    print("please select minimun 2 edges")
else:

    newmesh = bmesh.ops.bisect_edges(bm, edges=edges, cuts=5) #for example 5 cuts

    bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(use_extend=False, use_expand=False, type='VERT')
    print(newmesh['geom_split'])



bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bmesh.ops.bisect_edges` returns a dictionary that only has one item `geom_split`, that one item is a list of the data you want. You can easily find what everything is in the python console -

```
>>> newmesh.keys()
dict_keys(['geom_split'])
>>> newmesh['geom_split'].keys()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'
>>> len(newmesh['geom_split'])
12
>>> type(newmesh['geom_split'][0])
<class 'BMVert'>
>>> type(newmesh['geom_split'][11])
<class 'BMEdge'>
```

If you replace your `print()` with the following you can see the returned data.

```
for i in newmesh['geom_split']:
    if type(i) == bmesh.types.BMVert:
        print("Vertex",i.index,"positioned at",i.co)
    elif type(i) == bmesh.types.BMEdge:
        print("Edge from vert",i.verts[0].index,"to vert",i.verts[1].index)
```

While the api states that `bisect_edges` returns "newly created vertices and edges" I only see two edges returned.

Comment: really thanks, this open some new windows for my developments

Comment: For reference I [reported a bug](https://developer.blender.org/T43421) for the return value of bisect_edges, so this function may return more edges in later versions unless they change the docs to match the way it works now.